# Regex error in python but not PCRE2 (regex101.com)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to validate the following formats:

1. [1 Or More Upper-Case Letters not including X] e.g BY, BZ, B
2. [1 Or More Upper-Case Letters not including X][X][Any Number of Digits between 1-9] e.g. BYX11, BZX12, BX5

I developed this regular expression using regex101.com with the PCRE2 flavor

`^[A-WY-Z]+X*(?(?<=X)[1-9]+|$)$`

However it doesn't work when I switch it in Python - does anyone know what I need to change to get it working? It says incomplete group structure.

I tried updating it based on the python syntax to this, but it says the preceeding token to the conditional `(?<=X)` is not quantifiable.

`^[A-WY-Z]+X*((?<=X)?((1)[1-9]+)|$)$`

Anyone know how to get the top regex working in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
^[A-WY-Z]+(?:X[1-9]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrw53S/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-WY-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters other than `X`
- `(?:X[1-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of `X` and one or more non-zero digits
- `$` - end of string.